# Message formatting in a log file with python 2.7.9

Tags: python

I am a beginner in programming in Python.

I try to use the logging module to redirect a log to a file, but I am facing the following problem:

In my log file named " error.log " I have the level name and the date that recur in everyone of the log file lines.

Is there a way to avoid this problem?

I'm using Python 2.7.9.

Here is my code below :

```
# error.py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import logging
import sys
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.ERROR,
    format="%(levelname)s - %(asctime)s - %(message)s",
    filename="error.log",
    filemode='w'
)

class StreamToLogger(object):
    def __init__(self, logger, log_level=logging.DEBUG):
        self.logger = logger
        self.log_level = log_level

    def write(self, text):
        for line in text.rstrip().splitlines():
            self.logger.log(self.log_level, line.rstrip())

stdout_logger = logging.getLogger('STDOUT')
sl = StreamToLogger(stdout_logger, logging.INFO)
sys.stdout = sl
stderr_logger = logging.getLogger('STDERR')
sl = StreamToLogger(stderr_logger, logging.ERROR)
sys.stderr = sl
#Voluntary error for display in the log
print message
```

When I run this python script, I get the following file:

```
# the error.log file
ERROR - 2015-05-10 17:24:40,726 - Traceback (most recent call last):
ERROR - 2015-05-10 17:24:40,726 -   File "D:\error\error.py", line 27, in <module>
ERROR - 2015-05-10 17:24:40,726 - print message
ERROR - 2015-05-10 17:24:40,726 - NameError
ERROR - 2015-05-10 17:24:40,726 - :
ERROR - 2015-05-10 17:24:40,726 - name 'message' is not defined
```

Is there a way to avoid the repetition of the level name and the date to make my error message more readable?

Comment: Maybe try to change your `format` variable to something like this `format="%(message)s"`

Comment: Ah OK thanks to all.

I thought we could do it using methods such as filters, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are recursing, in `write`  you should be able to just set the first iteration for 
`self.logger.log(self.log_level, line.rstrip())`

and then have it change to something like 
`self.logger.log("", line.rstrip())`

for the rest of the values.

That *should* allow you to print the error level only once.

Answer (score 0):

The 'format' part:

```
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.ERROR,
    format="%(levelname)s - %(asctime)s - %(message)s",
    filename="error.log",
    filemode='w'
)
```

Defines how everything is printed to the console. If you keep just %(message)s, you'll get rid of the error level and timestamp.

If you're trying to keep just one occurence of the error level and timestamp (i.e.: remove all duplicates), I'm afraid there's no out-of-the box way to do it with the logging module.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, thanks to your advice, I could get what I wanted, ie, define the level name and the date only in the first line of my error file.

I changed the value of my format variable to "%(message)s" as you have advised me, and I formatted my first line in the loop.

I do not think this is the most elegant way, but it works like I wanted.

Here is my code:

```
# error.py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import logging
from datetime import datetime
import sys
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.ERROR,
    format="%(message)s",
    filename="error.log",
    filemode='w'
)

class StreamToLogger(object):
    def __init__(self, logger, log_level=logging.DEBUG):
        self.logger = logger
        self.log_level = log_level

    def write(self, text):
        textLines = text.splitlines()
        for line in textLines:
            if line.startswith("Traceback"):
                self.logger.log(self.log_level, "%s - %s - %s" % (logging.getLevelName(self.log_level), datetime.now(), line.rstrip()))
            else:
                self.logger.log(self.log_level, line.rstrip())

stdout_logger = logging.getLogger('STDOUT')
sl = StreamToLogger(stdout_logger, logging.INFO)
sys.stdout = sl
stderr_logger = logging.getLogger('STDERR')
sl = StreamToLogger(stderr_logger, logging.ERROR)
sys.stderr = sl
#Voluntary error for display in the log
print message
```

I get the following log file :

```
# error.log

ERROR - 2015-05-15 21:06:47.234000 - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\error\error.py", line 32, in <module>

print message

NameError
:
name 'message' is not defined
```